# R: How can I make a generic function read the class of arguments passed as a list?

Tags: r

Imagine I created a class "stem" with some S3 methods. i need to compare a number of stem objects with a function like

```
comp.default = function(smpc = x){
  message("I am default")
}

comp <- function(x) UseMethod("comp", x)

comp.stem = function(listOfStemObjects, print = TRUE, more args){ a bunch of things}

comp(list(stem1, stem2))
```

The function doesn't recognize the class because the first argument is of class "list" and not stem. Ideally I would like to pass a variable number of objects stem1, stem2,..

Any help?

Thanks in advance, marco

Answer (score 1):

```
comp <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("comp")

comp.stem <- function(x, ...)
{
    lst <- list(...)
    for(i in seq_along(lst))
    # do stuff with each additional object passed in
}

comp(stem1, stem2)
```

Comment: Ooi,that's great. but, list(...) does not seem to be a list. Good start. thanks.